# MassTransit ignores environment variables

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit

I'm trying to utilize Docker and environment variables but MassTransit seems to ignore them completely.

In my Dockerfile (amongst other things), I have this:

```
ENV MT_RMQ__HOST "rabbitmq"
ENV MT_RMQ__USER "root"
ENV MT_RMQ__PASS "root"
```

The following get applied just fine and display in Docker UI, but MassTransit still uses the same connection credentials:

```
Connect: guest@localhost:5672/

warn: MassTransit[0]

Retrying 00:00:08.2900000: Broker unreachable: guest@localhost:5672/
```

My configuration is simple:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) => cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context));
});

services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Comment: Where are you seeing that MassTransit uses environment variables? If you are using the MassTransit platform docker images, you do not call AddMassTransit with those, they are configured using a `IPlatformStartup` interface as per the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/platform/).

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I'm not using MassTransit platform docker images nor am I seeing environment variables being used. In fact, I'm seeing them NOT being used.

I have an ASPNET Core app with Mass Transit nuget package and a docker-contained RabbitMQ which runs without an issue.
The thing is, rabbitmq is hosted on separate container image - meaning I have to create network and utilize hostname - but I can't specify it because MT ignores ENV variables.

Comment: So, my point is, MassTransit doesn't use environment variables for any configuration. How you configure MassTransit is up to you.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I see. So, what can this be for? - https://masstransit-project.com/platform/configuration.html

Comment: For the MassTransit platform, which I linked above. Pre-built base Docker images for MassTransit applications that use `IPlatformStartup`.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson So, essentially I can host MassTransit as separate service and connect to it from my other services?

Comment: I'd suggest [watching this](https://youtu.be/-xEnO9H62lk) to get more details. The platform is an out-of-the-box way to host your consumers, sagas, etc. in Docker.